# Laravel how get all clients who were added by an employee from the same department

Tags: laravel

I have two table: Clients, Employees

**Clients structure:**

```
id
company_name
address
email
phone
created_by_employee
```

**Employees structure:**

```
id
name
position
department_id
```

I want to get all clients who were added by employees of the same department as the logged user.

So if I am logged in, I would like to get a list of my clients (added by me) and clients added by other employees, but only from my department (department_id). I have a problem with constructing a query in Laravel using join.

How can I build a query?

Comment: Use eloquent relationships. (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 1):

**Department Model**

```php
public function employees()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Employee::class);
}
```

**Employee Model**

```php
public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
}

public function clients()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Client::class, 'created_by_employee');
}
```

**Client Model**

```php
public function employee()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class,'created_by_employee');
}
```

Get clients who were added by an employee from the same department:

```php
$employee = App\Models\Employee::find(1);
$clients  = App\Models\Client::whereHas('employee', function ($query) use ($employee) {
    $query->where('department_id', $employee->department_id);
})->get();

return $clients;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using different tables then do.

**Your table**

```
$myId = auth()->user()->id; //you will need created_by_employee

$clients = Client::where('created_by_employee',$myID)->get();
```

**Others table**

**Client Model**

```
public function created_by()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\ Employees', 'id', 'created_by_employee');
}
```

*Not adding department_id on clients table might a mistake, unless if it's not
neccessary*

```
$myId = auth()->user()->id; //you will need created_by_employee
$departmentID = auth()->user()->department_id; //you will need 
 //department_id
 
 //join tables

 $clients = Client::join('employees','employees.id','clients. 
 created_by_employee')->where('clients.created_by_employee','!=',$myID)- 
 >where('employees.id',$departmentID)- 
 >groupBy('clients.id')- 
 >select('clients.id','clients.company_name','clients. 
 created_by_employee','ect........')->with('created_by')->get();
```

**For same table**

```
$myId = auth()->user()->id; //you will need created_by_employee
$departmentID = auth()->user()->department_id; //you will need 
 //department_id
 
 //join tables

 $clients = Client::join('employees','employees.id','clients. 
 created_by_employee')->where('employees.id',$departmentID)- 
 >groupBy('clients.id')- 
 >select('clients.id','clients.company_name','clients. 
 created_by_employee','ect........')->with('created_by')->get();
```

*You created_y to know who the client belongs to or who created the client*